# Notation for element of matrix

Tags: notation

I am wondering what is a proper way to refer to a single or multipe elements taken from a bigger matrix. Lets say there is the matrix $A$. If I want to pick a single element, I would write something like this:

$b = A_{12}$, $b = (A)_{12}$,

and for multiple elements, this:

$b = A_{1:2,3}$, $b = A_{[1:2,3]}$

Is there some better or more appropriate notation? Do you have ideas how to write this in a better way?

Comment: The first notation is common. The second notation, for multiple elements, is non-standard, but ther isn't any standard notation that I know of, and you can use any notation if you define it before using it and it is well-defined.

Comment: For example, would $1:3$ mean $\{1,2,3\}$ or $\{1,3\}?$

Comment: You could also write $(A_{ij})_{i\in\{1,2\},j=3}.$